# UICollectionView: How To Reorder Without Long Press

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My UICollectionView adds a longPress gesture to each cell so that holding prompts an alert box allowing the user to hide or delete the cell. However, now I want to add the [iOS9 UICollectionView reordering](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/reordering-collection-view-cells-tutorial) feature, but it uses a long press.

My problem is, I want to a long press to continue to trigger the alert box so the user can hide or delete that cell. The solution I want is to add a third alert action called "Move Cells". **My question is,** can I trigger the the UICollectionView drag and drop functionality on a button press, like a UITableView edit mode?

Comment: How do you want to trigger the start of the Drag? If you start the drag immediately, you'll never get to your long press action (or didSelect if you're using that). You'll also run into trouble with scrolling the collection. One option could be to start the drag action on double-tap...

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/ra1028/RAReorderableLayout for easy approach and for long press you can add

```
 let tap: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(myVC.rearrange))
        cell.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

either at creating of collection view cell or in `awakeFromNib`